# awk regex can't match ip addresses when trying to find repeating digits

Tags: regex, awk

I can't get the following to match any IP addresses

```
awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}' maillog
```

or this one...

```
awk '/[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}/' maillog
```

but this works...

```
awk '/127.0.0.1/{print $0}' maillog
```

and so does this...

```
awk '/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/{print $0}' maillog
```

What am I doing wrong in the first two?

Comment: Older awk versions don't support `{...}` but gnu-awk does

Comment: Try `awk  --re-interval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `interval` `{1,3}` with `gnu awk` you my need to enable it with `--re-interval` like this:

```
awk --re-interval '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}' maillog
```

Comment: @majikman Get a newer gawk as RE intervals have been on by default for several releases now. You don't need `{print $0}` that's the default behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton That is easy to say.  I have used Ubuntu from 8x to 13x, still re interval has not been in `awk` as default.  You need to go to `awk` 4.x to get it.  I try to use my OS as is, since it would give me less problems. If you do `apt-get install gawk` you get `gawk is already the newest version.` so you need to manually install it.

Comment: @Jotne I use Ubuntu 12.04, and I downloaded it from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/gawk-4.1.0.tar.xz and installed it manually on the `/scratch` drive using `./configure --prefix=/scratch/gawk-4.1` later I just made an alias to the binary as `alias awk4='/scratch/gawk-4.1/bin/gawk'`. I now have both version 3.1.8 and version 4.1.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I know it could be done, but many user does not know how to do this. I like my system as simple as possible, so I will not install it if I do not really need it.  But thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

They are just fine.

The following is working for me.

```
$ echo "2.168.1.1" | awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}'
2.168.1.1

$ echo "2.1.1.1" | awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}'
2.1.1.1

$ echo "22.1.1.1" | awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $0}'
22.1.1.1
```

I would investigate your maillog and make sure that everything there is in plaintext.

Comment: strange... none of those work for me. I'm using GNU Awk 3.1.7. You?

Comment: $ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 5.1.3)